# In R how do I set the column value for rows that are in a list of indexes?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of row indexes that represent rows of interest from a dataframe.

`> inds [1]    1   3  6  9  11`

I have a list of filenames that I want to match up with these row indexes and populate a column in the dataframe with.

```
 [1] "C:/Temp/file/Company ABC.docx"                                         
 [2] "C:/Temp/file/Company DFE.docx"                              
 [3] "C:/Temp/file/Company YTS.docx"                                    
 [4] "C:/Temp/file/Business ABC.docx"                         
 [5] "C:/Temp/file/Business DFG.docx"
```

So for example, row 1 (which is index 1 from inds), will have the FileName populated with the first item from the filenames list.
Row 3 (which is index 3 from inds) will have the FileNames populated with the second item from filenames list.

| Row1 | FileName |
| --- | --- |
| blah blah | C:/Temp/file/Company ABC.docx |
| blah blah | NA |
| blah blah | C:/Temp/file/Company DFE.docx |

At the moment I have this code:

```
   for (i in inds){
    for(j in 1:length(filenames)){
     df$FileName [i] <- filenames[j]
    }
  }
```

Currently, this isn't working, it is just populating all the rows in inds with the last filename from the filenames list. I assume it is re-writing over it within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly use the index instead of a loop i.e. create a the 'FileName' as a `NA` column and then assign the values i.e. filenames based on the 'inds'

```
df$FileName <- NA_character_
df$FileName[inds] <- filenames
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[inds, FileName := filenames]
```

---

The `for` loop doesn't need nested loop.  A single loop is needed and that too on the sequence of either the 'inds' or the 'filenames'

```
df$FileName <- NA_character_
for(i in seq_along(inds)) {
    df$FileName[ind[i]] <- filenames[i]
}
```